# Will storing blue cheese with other cheeses make them mold faster?

Tags: cheese, mold

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I eat cheese which has been “infected” with blue cheese mold?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/20423/can-i-eat-cheese-which-has-been-infected-with-blue-cheese-mold)

A while ago I got a chunk of blue cheese and stored it in the fridge.  A little later, we bought some cheddar cheese and I stored it in teh same compartment of the fridge as the blue cheese. Now the cheddar cheese has mold on it. I've never seen mold on cheddar cheese appear this quickly, so I'm wondering if having the blue cheese in my fridge actually makes mold appear on my other cheeses more quickly?

Comment: Is the mold blue?

Comment: Did you taste it?

Comment: I would close this as a dup of http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/20423/can-i-eat-cheese-which-has-been-infected-with-blue-cheese-mold, what do you people think?

Comment: @rumtscho I'd say it depends whether the mold is blue or not.

Comment: Since the OP has not returned to respond to any of the request for clarification, I'm closing this as a dupe. We'll consider reopening if it turns out to be something totally different.